# What is the meaning of " *navbar " in <ion-navbar>?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Whenever I follow the tutorial of ionic I see the phrase `*navbar`. 
what is the meaning of this? I know that * means it is inserting the tag inside the template but cannot really understand for this expression..

```
<ion-navbar secondary *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    <ion-searchbar primary placeholder="enter subreddit name..."></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-title>

  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="openSettings()"><ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: why vote down? i have same question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you say (and just like you can read [here](http://learnangular2.com/templates/))

the asterisk indicates that this directive *treats this component as a template and will not draw it as-is*. For example, ngFor takes our  and stamps it out for each item in items, but it never renders our initial  since it’s a template:

```
<my-component *ngFor="#item of items">
</my-component>
```

So, as I understand, the `*navbar` tells the navbar component that the ion-navbar tag should be replaced by the template rather than rendered inside it. That's why your code:

```
<ion-navbar secondary *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    <ion-searchbar primary placeholder="enter subreddit name..."></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-title>

  <ion-buttons end>
    <button (click)="openSettings()"><ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Is then rendered as something like this:

```
<ion-navbar class="toolbar show-navbar" secondary="">
    <div class="toolbar-background"></div>
    <button category="bar-button" class="back-button bar-button bar-button-default"><span class="button-inner"><span class="button-inner"><ion-icon class="back-button-icon ion-md-arrow-back" role="img" aria-label="arrow back"></ion-icon><span class="back-button-text"><span class="back-default"></span></span>
        </span>
        <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
        </span>
        <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
    </button>
    <ion-buttons end="">
        <button class="bar-button bar-button-default bar-button-icon-only"><span class="button-inner"><ion-icon name="settings" role="img" class="ion-md-settings" aria-label="settings"></ion-icon></span>
            <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <div class="toolbar-content">
        <ion-title>
            <div class="toolbar-title">
                <ion-searchbar placeholder="enter subreddit name..." primary="" class="">
                    <div class="searchbar-input-container">
                        <button class="searchbar-md-cancel button button-clear button-icon-only button-clear-dark" clear="" dark=""><span class="button-inner"><ion-icon name="arrow-back" role="img" class="ion-md-arrow-back" aria-label="arrow back"></ion-icon></span>
                            <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
                        </button>
                        <div class="searchbar-search-icon"></div>
                        <input autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" class="searchbar-input" spellcheck="false" type="search" placeholder="enter subreddit name...">
                        <button class="searchbar-clear-icon button button-clear" clear=""><span class="button-inner"></span>
                            <ion-button-effect></ion-button-effect>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <button class="searchbar-ios-cancel button button-clear activated" clear=""><span class="button-inner">Cancel</span>
                        <ion-button-effect style="left: -9999px; transform: scale(0.001) translateZ(0px);"></ion-button-effect>
                    </button>
                </ion-searchbar>
            </div>
        </ion-title>


    </div>
</ion-navbar>
```

Don't pay too much attention to the code, I just wanted to show you how your code that looks so simple is then rendered as such a complex block of code.

So, *the way I understand it*, is that you are just saying to Ionic that you want to use the `navbar` template (by using `*navbar`), and sending information about a title, a button and what content they should have and where those things should be placed (with attributes like `end`). Then Ionic will handle to use that information to fill out the template and render the HTML code.

Comment: thanks for the kind explanation :) i was too curious i think Thanks again!